# New front door handle/deadbolt installation

Tags: doors

New front door handle/deadbolt installation will not lock from inside house using knob will lock from outside using key but key will not come out until key is turned back into unlock position

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home  Improvement. Who installed this door handle, and  why won't they fix it? Pictures of the inside and outside would also help.

Comment: This almost always means that something is not assembled correctly. If you installed it, take it apart and try again, double-checking anything you might have missed in the directions. If someone else did, they should make it right.

Comment: try it with the door open as a test, does it make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Your knob and key are out of sync.  Split the lock. Rotate the knob 90 degrees or 180 if 90 isn't an option.  Screw the lock back together. I ran into this exact issue with a double cylinder deadbolt when installing it in our home.